# Convert a recursive method to loop method

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, recursion

```
async function treeTraverser(userId) {
  if (userId !== null) {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).select("-password");

    graphUsers.push(user);
    treeTraverser(user.directions.left);
    treeTraverser(user.directions.right);
  }
}
```

I want to convert this function into a looping function.

```
user.directions
```

is an object which contains Ids of other users

```
user.directions: {
  left: someId,
  right: someId
}
```

I shall be thankful to amazing community of developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function iterativePreOrderTraverser(userId) {
  if (userId === null) return;
  const nodeStack = [];
  nodeStack.push(userId);

  while (nodeStack.length > 0) {
    let poppedUserId = nodeStack.pop();
    const user = await User.findById(poppedUserId);
    graphUsers.push(user);

    if (user.directions.right !== null) {
      nodeStack.push(user.directions.right);
    }

    if (user.directions.left !== null) {
      nodeStack.push(user.directions.left);
    }
  }
```

Basically my question contains a preorder tree traversal code. So I searched on the internet and found a solution on [Geek For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-preorder-traversal/) and it solved the problem through loops. It didn't contain javascript code but I could convert python code to javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function treeTraverser(userId) {
  if (userId !== null) {
    const user = await User.findById(userId).select("-password");
    graphUsers.push(user);
  }
}


Object.keys(user.directions).forEach((key) => {
        treeTraverser(user.direction[key])
})
```